# Will ajax call return successfully to reloaded web page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events

I have a beginner question. If I make an ajax call using JavaScript, and then successfully reload the page before the ajax request gets a response, will the response still work?

Comment: Nope, reloading the page will terminate any script running within that page

Comment: I've never actually thought about it, but logic dictates that being very unlikely. The AJAX call would involve the client page listening for a response; once you load the page, the listener would disappear. The server would probably send a response, but it would "fall on deaf ears" as the client would be no longer listening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you mean by 'work'. The request will still be sent to the server, and the server will send back a response, but any callback functions which you have assigned to be executed when the response is received will not run, because the function objects that were assigned will have been lost when the page was reloaded.

Comment: Could you be more specific? The ajax response is returned and what it is looking for is a callback function, which is still there with the same name. Do you know specifically what is out of synch in the function objects so that the response will not process? Maybe I mean how are the function objects assigned?

Comment: I think the exact details of what happens will be browser-specific, but I would assume that any HTTP connections which were opened on the previous page will be closed when the page is reloaded, so there won't be any way to coerce functions defined in the new page to receive data from requests that were sent on the old page.

Answer (score 3):

No.

By reloading the page, all JavaScript (and its parser/engine) is terminated, reset and initialized again. So any pending (Ajax) calls are aborted. Hence, existing calls it will not work anymore.

Furthermore, all active (HTTP) connection are (should be) reset, so the server might still process the request (if it arrived on time), but the response is lost due to the aborted connections.

The fact that these things are not working after a reload, is a good thing: As it would result in unexpected, error-prone situations!

Comment: Thanks for answering. Please see my follow up question to codebox.